# edit Symfony2 big entity in form with tabs

Tags: forms, symfony, tabs, symfony-forms

I'm building form using Sf2's form builder.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')...
```

The Entity has a lot of fields and I'd like to put them in jQuery UI Tabs. But in twig template I'd like to use single command

```
<form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

What is best solution?

edit **

To be more conrete: I have 4 fields: firstName, lastName, birthDate, deathDate. I want first 2 fields to be on first tab and the last 2 fields to be on second tab. I want to keep way of rendering the form as mentioned earlier.

I though of a solution to create my own fields not conneceted to underlaying object which will render required html tags (h3, div, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I defined my own field called 'Tab' and add it when new tab should appear.

```
<?php
//\src\Alden\xyzBundle\Form\Type\TabsType.php

namespace Alden\BonBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormValidatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;

class TabsType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('starting', $options['starting']);
        $builder->setAttribute('ending', $options['ending']);
        $builder->setAttribute('header', $options['header']);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
    {
        $parent = $form->getParent();
        if (is_null($parent->getParent()))
        {
            $tabs = $this->findTabs($parent);
        }
        else
        {
            $tabs = array();
        }
        $view->set('starting', $form->getAttribute('starting'));
        $view->set('ending', $form->getAttribute('ending'));
        $view->set('header', $form->getAttribute('header'));
        $view->set('tabs', $tabs);
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'property_path' => false,
            'starting' => true,
            'ending' => true,
            'header' => false,
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tabs';
    }

    public function getParent(array $options)
    {
        return 'field';
    }

    private function findTabs(Form $form)
    {
        $prefix = $form->getName();
        $tabs = array();
        foreach ($form->getChildren() as $child)
        {
            foreach ($child->getTypes() as $type)
            /* @var $child \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
            {
                if (get_class($type) == __NAMESPACE__ . '\TabsType')
                {
                    if ($child->getAttribute('starting'))
                    {
                        $tabs[$prefix . '_' . $child->getName()] = $child->getAttribute('label');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $tabs;
    }

}

?>
```

and Twig

```
{# \src\Alden\xyzBundle\Resources\views\Form\fields.html.twig #}
{% block tabs_row %}
{% if header %}
<ul>
    {% for tid, t in tabs %}
        <li>
            <a href="#{{ tid }}">{{ t }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% if ending %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if starting %}
<div id="{{ id }}">
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and usage in form builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('tabs_head', new TabsType(), array(
                'ending' => false,
                'starting' => false,
                'header' => true
            ))
            ->add('tab_1', new TabsType(), array(
                'ending' => false,
                'label' => 'Podstawowe'
            ))
            ->add('firstName', null, array(
                'label' => 'Imię'
            ))
            ->add('lastName', null, array(
                'label' => 'Nazwisko'
            ))
            ->add('tab_contact', new TabsType(), array(
                'label' => 'Kontakt'
            ))
            ->add('address', new AddressType(), array(
                'label' => 'Adres zameldowania'
            ))
            ->add('tabs_end', new TabsType(), array(
                'starting' => false
            ))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a form to act like a form wizard you could look at look at the [multi-step form bundle](http://knpbundles.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle)

It's pretty nice, you can for example, define step one as filling in software details and then on step2, fill out version details. or whatever you want.

**Features**

- navigation (next, back, start over)
- step descriptions
- skipping of specified steps
- different validation group for each step
- dynamic step navigation

And [here](http://www.craue.de/sf2playground/en/CraueFormFlow/) is a live demo

Comment: I need to load all the form fields at once.

Answer (score 0):

> But in twig template I'd like to use single command

Do you mean to render the fields?

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

renders all unrendered forms